# CD not DVD installer

Tags: cd

I want to install Ubuntu on a pc that won't boot from USB sticks. I don't have any blank DVDs. Is there something that will fit on a blank CD?

Answer (score 1):

There's an [alternate download](https://code.google.com/p/ubuntucd/) which uses a more powerful compression method, and all of the standard 13.10 release fits on a CD using their technique.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will not fit to an CD, only to a DVD.

You can use a Netboot-Image to boot from CD. The rest of the files needed for the installation will be donwloaded during the installation process. Of course you need an internet-connection to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install 12.10 or 13.04, the only way is a DVD or USB, but since you stated that you can't boot from USB, you can download 12.04, and it will fit on a CD.

Then you can upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 then to Ubuntu 13.04.  Or the easy way, you can wait till you get some blank DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Use an alternate install. Go to [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) and look for the *network installer*. I've never personally used this method, but it's where I'd start.